# OpenAM thinks it is not configured

Tags: openam, opends

I was running OpenAM fine for a couple of weeks, had created trees, policies, etc.

Today when I went to try to login I was prompted with the installation screen:

> Create Default Configuration

> Create New Configuration

As far as I can tell this happened after I dropped a new schema on the external OpenDS. But now I can't get rid of the error even after removing the schema file. Have I messed things up or can I recover my previous configuration?

Comment: You could add JVM options '-Dcom.iplanet.services.debug.level=message' '-Dcom.iplanet.services.debug.directory=WRITABLE_EXISTING_DIRECTORY' to troubleshoot bootstrapping issues. Most likely AM can find its configuration data store or can not communicate with it. If you are using bootstrap hint in '$HOME/.openamcfg' (which would be the default), check if this file exists and that the content points to the correct OpenAM configuation directory. Then check the bootstrap file.

Comment: Thank you, this allowed me to see that it was a problem with file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Bernhard Thalmayr allowed me to solve this issue by seeing that the problem was a file permission that was assigned to root instead of the user running OpenAM